# Dataweave 2.0 withMaxSize function

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I've transformation in external dwl file. I'm trying to use 'withMaxSize' to limit the size of string. But I'm getting below issue.

```
fun providerObjMapping(payload) = (if(! isEmpty(payload.ProviderUniqueID) ) {

  providerUniqueID:payload.ProviderUniqueID dw::core::Strings::withMaxSize 3,
  npi:payload.NPI,
  salutation:payload.Salutation,
  firstName:payload.FirstName,
  middleName:payload.MiddleName

  }else {})
```

""Script '%dw 2.0
import * from dw::appian_crf_mapping

```
output application/json
---
generateObj(vars.tableName, payload) ' has errors:


    Unable to resolve reference of dw::core::Strings::withMaxSize. at 29 : 29" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
import * from dw::appian_crf_mapping

output application/json
---
generateObj(vars.tableName, payload)"."
```

Below are the ways I've tried.

1. providerUniqueID:payload.ProviderUniqueID dw::core::Strings::withMaxSize 3   - Not Working
2. fun maxLength(data) = data dw::core::Strings::withMaxSize 3
   providerUniqueID:maxLengh(payload.ProviderUniqueID)     -  not Working
3. import * dw::core::Strings
   fun maxLength(data) = data withMaxSize 3
   providerUniqueID:maxLengh(payload.ProviderUniqueID)   - not working

Runtime: 4.2.1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3KSp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MuleSoft documentation, withMaxSize was introduced in DataWeave 2.3.0, supported by Mule Runtime 4.3.0 or later (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-strings-functions-withmaxsize)

As you are using Mule Runtime 4.2.1, you could implement the withMaxSize function as:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun withMaxSize(val, maxSize) = val[0 to (((min([sizeOf(val), maxSize])) as Number) - 1)]
---
withMaxSize(payload.message, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

withMaxSize function: It is only available 4.3.0 runtime or onwards.

Please checkout our Relaese Notes for more Info:
[Release Notes 4.3.0 Runtime](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-runtime/mule-4.3.0-release-notes)

Please use 4.3.0 version of Runtime .It will work for you.